# How can I add an element to a list that is sorted so that it keeps sorted?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, binary-search

Suppose I have a `List<int> list` that is sorted.

I want to add a new element `x` to the list so that it keeps sorted in the end.

Basically there would be 2 cases: if `x > list[list.Count-1]`, then only `list.Add(x)` is needed.

Otherwise, a binary search would be needed for better performance, so I would be able to find an index `i` and call `list.Insert(x, i)`. Is there anything ready that I can make use of?

---

Just to clarify the problem I'm solving.

There is a big list **L** and I have a window of size **n** that moves from the beginning to the end of **L** per iteration:

```
n = 4
L = 8 4 1 9 0 4 3 4 8 5 1 9 0 6 4 3 2 4
   [8 4 1 9]0 4 3 4 8 5 1 9 0 6 4 3 2 4   at i = 0
    8[4 1 9 0]4 3 4 8 5 1 9 0 6 4 3 2 4   at i = 1
    8 4[1 9 0 4]3 4 8 5 1 9 0 6 4 3 2 4   at i = 2
    8 4 1[9 0 4 3]4 8 5 1 9 0 6 4 3 2 4   at i = 3
    ...................................
```

and for each window, I have to sent the median of it to another function, so the most performant way I could thing of was sort the whole window in i = 0 and for each step in the iterations, I remove the first element and replace by a new one and call Sort again.

Comment: Did you actually try to perform the most obvious "add at the end and push it up" approach - you can't get better than O(n) anyway so binary search is likely unnecessary complication. Make sure to use good time measuring framework to compare different implementations - i.e. https://benchmarkdotnet.org/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You are describing [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-6.0).

Comment: It may be good idea to [edit] post to clarify that using `BinarySearch` will not improve performance in most practical cases where comparison is cheap (like in OP's case where they comparing integers)

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<T>.FindIndex` to find the index of the first item where x is greater. Then just insert as you normally would.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a new element x to the list so that it keeps sorted in the end.

If you don't care about inserting it at the correct position and only that it is sorted when you're done, there's [`List.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0).

Then just:

```
list.Add(x);
list.Sort();
```

If your object is more complex than an `int` you can provide a comparer.

Comment: That would make the algorithm scale from O(n) to O(n lg(n)). For the cases where the input is too big, it might cause time issues. I will also keep the list with a fixed size, so I'll be constantly adding an element and removing another, so calling Sort all the time would not be as efficient as possible.